# "Superglobals are available throughout a script" - what constitutes a script?

Tags: php

What does "throughout a script" mean?  When are 2 php documents part of a same script and when are they not?

Comment: It means "throughout the execution of your program".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Throughout a script" means "throughout one invocation of the PHP interpreter". Here are some typical situations:

- Script A `include()`s or `require()`s Script B: The superglobals will transmute from Script A to Script B
- Script A `eval()`s some code: The superglobals will transmute from the script to the argument of the evaluation.

This is different to "super-defines" such as `__FILE__`, as superglobals will be constant (if not manually changed) throughout the invocation, while super-defines will not.

In addition to that, the superglobals will allways be in scope, even if inside a function or class without explicitly being `global`ed

Answer (score 3):

Without getting into nitty gritty, pedantic details, the easiest way to think of it is that super globals are available throughout the entire execution.

More over, the *same* super globals are available throughout an execution.  In other words, you can have five levels of includes and all kinds of function call nesting, but `$_GET['key']`, `$_SERVER['key']`, etc is still the same variable for that execution.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that they are available for the complete execution of your script.

This means that they are also available in any script which you include or require in your primary script (remember that including a script is effectively the same as copying and pasting the code, it's just easier to maintain).

They are also available in any functions within your script.

Note that they differ from global variables in that they do not have to be preceded by 'global' in order for them to be accessible in functions.

I hope this helps.